# Exception "Illegal character in query at index -" in Android

Tags: java, android, web-services, exception

I am trying to send data on server using following link.

```
**WEBSERVICE LINK:**
http://75.125.237.76/post_reviews.php?data=text1
```

If I set data filed with single string (ex:data=text1), That time my try block in source code working fine, without any exception.

But When I set data field with multiple string with spaces (ex: data=text1 text2 text3), Then Exception generated i.e. Illegal character in query.

```
**EXCEPTION:**
Illegal character in query at index 75: http://75.125.237.76/post_reviews.php?data=text1 text2 text3
```

**My question is Why exception generate when we use multiple strings (like: data=My name is xyz).**

If I replace data field with single string that time is working fine.(data=xyz)

Comment: Thanx for all answer. My problem is solved with                        data = data.replaceAll(" ", "%20"); thanx all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Encode `space` with `%20` have a look at [this one for more encodings](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Encode your URI string so the spaces will be presented as %20